# One-one correspondence between covectors on a manifold and on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: manifolds, tangent-spaces

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional manifold and $p \in U \subset M$. Let $k: O \rightarrow U$ be a coordinate chart where $O \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ (here I follow Weintraub's *Differential Forms: Theory and Practice* in defining a coordinate chart as a map from a Euclidean space to the manifold). Let $r_1$ and $r_2$ be the parametrizations of two curves on $M$ with $r_1(0) = r_2(0) = p$. We say that these two curves are equivalent if $(k{}^{-1} \circ r_1)'(0) = (k{}^{-1} \circ r_2)'(0)$. Then the tangent vectors to $M$ at $p$ are defined as the equivalence classes of curves on $M$ passing through $p$.

Now according to Weintraub, there is a one-one correspondence between the tangent vectors on $M$ and those on $O$. I wonder if there is also a one-one correspondence between the covectors on $M$ and those on $O$.

Comment: if two finite-dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic, then so are their dual spaces, simply for dimension reasons, but in fact the transpose/dual mapping of the original isomorphism gives an isomorphism between the duals (i.e if $T:V\to W$ is an isomorphism between finite-dimensional spaces, then $T^*:W^*\to V^*$ is also an isomorphism).

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. Then I have a further question. Is there also a one-one correspondence between $k$-covectors (or $k$-forms) on $M$ and those on $O$?

Comment: Yes, again, it is a simple linear algebra exercise. Regarding forms, it is k-forms on $O$ and $U$ (not $M$) which are in bijective correspondence.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.